# Javascript Complex classes

Tags: javascript, web-services

I have the folowing scenario:-

I need to create a Request class (in Javascript) with the following structure

```
<Request>
   <a/>
   <filter>
      <x/>
      <y/>
      <z/>
   </filter>
   <c/>
   <d/>
</Request>
```

The initial question is, how do I accomplish this in Javascript.

Now, for the broader picture:- 
This request is an input to a Script Service. So, is this a best practice to *create* the request object at the client rather than obtain them somehow. If not what is the best practice in doing so

Answer (score 1):

in this blog there is a [tutorial](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) how to create Javascript class.

so I suppose you would star by doing something like

```
var request = {
    a: "macintosh",
    c: "red",
    d: "a",
    filter: function (a,b,c) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've described and XML structure. Is this a required format, or are you open to JSON?  I would suggest the later.  Also, is this data to be sent with AJAX, or is it to be part of a subsequent POST/GET form submission, etc?

To create a JSON object and its representative string

```
var request = {
    a: 1,
    filter: {
        x: 4,
        y: 5,
        z: 6
    },
    c: 2,
    d: 3
};
```

To convert it to a string, you can use something as simple as Firefox's `JSON` object, although **I highly suggest that you use a more portable library** like Dojo or jQuery (available as a plugin) to accomplish this.

FF:

```
JSON.stringify(request);
```

Dojo:

```
dojo.toJson(request);
```

jQuery

```
$.toJSON(request);
```

Comment: what about the second part of the question?